# Laravel Redirect from Different Function

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to make an authorization code validator that can be used throughout multiple instances of my website... I want to make it so if the validation fails, it will redirect the user from within the validation function (but this is not working) (similar to how laravels native validation system works for form data). Here are snippets of my code showing the issue.

```
// From a custom controller (AccountController.php)
public function requestValidate(Request $request, $token)
{
   $user = Auth::user();

   // This call should redirect to the homepage if the verification fails...
   // but instead... it does not redirect and executes return view('verified');
   $user->verifyAuthToken($request, $token);

   return view('verified');
 }

 // From User.php 
 public function verifyAuthToken(Request $request, $token)
 {
    if (trim($this->auth_code) === '' || trim($token) === '' || $this->auth_code !== $token) {
       $request->session()->flash('error', 'Sorry, an error occurred. Please try again.');

       // THIS DOES NOT REDIRECT
       return redirect()->route('profile');
    }

    $this->auth_code = "";
    $this->save();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

in your code
`return redirect()->route('profile');`
this only break the process in your verifyAuthToken function, but not your requestValidate. So basically after the page is redirected to profile, it will redirected again to verified page.
So, maybe you can give a return True in authentication success, then in requestValidate you can do like this:

```
if($user->verifyAuthToken($request, $token)){
  return view('verified');
}
```

Comment: I figured something like this would work, but I wanted to do it in the verifyAuthToken function... When we use use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator this automatically redirects without having to check if the validation failed or not.